# What is the norm of the functional $F: C[0,1] \to \mathbb C, F(f) = \int_0^1f(t)g(t) \, dt$ with $g \in L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $g \in L^1[0,1]$ be a (complex-valued) integrable function on $[0,1]$. Consider the map
$$
F: C[0,1] \to \mathbb C, \ \ F(f) = \int_0^1f(t)g(t) \, dt.
$$
This map is a bounded linear functional on the space $C[0,1]$ w.r.t. the supremum norm. Is it true that the norm of $F$ (as a linear functional) is equal to the $L^1$-norm of $g$, i.e.
$$
\| F \| = \| g \|_{L^1[0,1]}.
$$
My attempt would be to use the Riesz representation theorem: $F$ is represented by a unique complex regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ and the norm of $F$ is the total variation of $\mu$. Is it true that in the above case this measure is simply $g dt$ and the total variation of $g dt$ is the $L^1$-norm of $g$?

Answer (score 2):

One inequality is fairly straightforward:
$$
     |F(f)| \le \int_0^1|f(t)||g(t)|dt 
                 \le \|g\|_{L^1[0,1]}\|f\|_{C[0,1]}.
$$
This gives
$$
                 \|F\|\le \|g\|_{L^1[0,1]}.
$$
To show the opposite inequality, let $0 < a < b < 1$, and choose $h > 0$ small enough that $h < a$ and $h < 1-b$. Let $f_{a,b,h}$ be the piecewise linear and continuous function that is given by
$$
      f_{a,b,h}(t)=   \int_0^x\frac{1}{h}\chi_{[a-h,a]}(t)-\frac{1}{h}\chi_{[b,b+h]}(t) dt.
$$
This function is piecewise linear and continuous. It is $0$ on $[0,a-h]$, rises linearly to $1$ at $a$, remains $1$ on $[a,b]$, declines linearly to $0$ at $b+h$ and is $0$ on $[b+h,1]$. Then,
$$
      F(f_{a,b,h})=\int_0^1f_{a,b,h}(t)g(t)dt \\
     \lim_{h\downarrow 0}F(f_{a,b,h})=\int_a^b g(t)dt
$$
Therefore, for all $0 \le a < b \le 1$,
$$
     \left|\int_a^bg(t)dt\right| \le \lim_{h\downarrow 0}|F(f_{a,b,h})|\le \|F\|\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\|f_{a,b,h}\|=\|F\|(b-a) \\
      \left|\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(t)dt\right|\le \|F\|.
$$
Therefore,
$$
       |g(x)| \le \|F\|,\;\; a.e. x\in [0,1] \\
      \implies \|g\|_{L^1[0,1]} \le \|F\|
$$
Therefore, $\|F\|=\|g\|_{L^1[0,1]}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the measure corresponding to $F$ is given by $\mu (E)=\int _E g(t)dt$ and $|\mu| (E)=\int_E |g(t)|dt$ (Theorem 6.13 in Rudin's RCA) so $\|\mu\|=\|g\|_{L^{1}}$.